# How to insert query and see the result in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite

I'd like to know if tables exists. I got to know that I should use "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table';"

So, what I did :

```
let query = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table';"
let res = contactDB.executeQuery(infoss, withArgumentsIn: [])
```

but how do I display the result in Xcode console or textview?

or is there any other way to approach and get the result?

Comment: If you only want to see if a table exists then use a SQLite client like [DB Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) or access the database using the Terminal

Comment: What is `contactDB` and what type does it have?